# Ajax getting form data and url

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am **learning** AJAX by following some online tutorials and getting help from the very kind SO community when stuck. I am slowly getting the hang of it.

My question is based on 2 different tutorials I am following for a contact form

***Tutorial 1 does the follwoing:***

```
jQuery.ajax({
        url: "contact_mail.php",
        data:'userName='+$("#userName").val()+'&userEmail='+$("#userEmail").val()+'&subject='+$("#subject").val()+'&content='+$(content).val(),
        type: "POST",
        success:function(data){
        $("#mail-status").html(data);
        },
        error:function (){}
        });
```

***Tutorial 2 does the follwoing:***

```
var formData = $(form).serialize();
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: $(form).attr('action'),
            data: formData
        })
        .done(function(response) {
```

**My question**

Unfortunately both tutorials does not really cover the `url` and `data` attributes in the ajax call and this is where my question comes in.

1. Where tutorial1 physically gets all the form fields i.e `data:'userName='+$("#userName").val()+` tutorial2 simply does the following `data: formData`

Thus am I correct in saying that you do not physically have to get all the form fields like in tutorial1 but rather you can just get the whole form and assign it to a variable and send that as data?

2. Tutorial 1 hardcodes the `url` where tutorial2 gets the form and assign the action attribute to the `url: $(form).attr('action')`,

Thus am I correct in saying that you do not have to hardcode the URL but rather get it from the form and assign the attribute action to the url?

3. Which example/ tutorial is the better one in terms of best practice?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first question, [jQuery's .serialize()](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) will take a given form or individual inputs/selects/etc. and produce a string of URL-encoded parameters to be sent via `POST` or `GET`. This is a very handy thing to do when working with forms. Tutorial 1 is effectively doing the same thing as tutorial 2 by manually constructing this string.

Tutorial 2 seems preferable over Tutorial 1 here, as Tutorial 1 is far more repetitive and, as such, less maintainable and more error prone. However, a mixture of the two may sometimes be needed, as you may sometimes want to send additional data in the request that isn't in the form.

For your second question, it doesn't really make too much of a difference what you do here, but you'd probably be better off placing the URL in your markup rather than your code, since you'd typically generate URLs when using a typical Web Framework, and it's good practice to treat HTML as templates and JS/CSS as static assets (you wouldn't want to template your JavaScript with URLs).

However, this situation might be different if you were using a front-end framework like Angular or Ember.

Answer (score 2):

As per my view **Tutorial2** is good because there he has written that particular `ajax` method in terms of General action i.e. you can have one single ajax function for submitting any number of forms. Say I have below ajax wrapped in a `function()`

```
function submitForm(form){ //accepts form as parameter
    var formData = $(form).serialize(); //serialize this particular form
    $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: $(form).attr('action'), //get value from forms action attrbute
              data: formData
    }).done(function(response) {

    });
}
```

Now say I have 2 `form`s as below

```
<form id="frm1" action="Page1.html" onsubmit="submitForm(this)">
        .....    
</form>

<form id="frm2" action="Page2.html" onsubmit="submitForm(this)">
        .....    
</form>
```

Now from both the forms you are passing form itself as `parameter` to the `function` which the `function` manipulates using the `js` written above

Now the **Tutorial1** might be just to understand for the starters what values should be there or how it works around.

Answer (score 1):

1. `$(form).serialize();` Basically does what is typed out in the first example for you automatically.
   See https://api.jquery.com/serialize/
2. Yes you can set the url however you want, tutorial 2 uses the current forms action. You could set this via a variable or hardcode it depending on what your goal is. In this case since the tutorial is showing you how to submit a normal form via ajax they will always use the form they are submitting's action
3. The second tutorial seems much cleaner but is for the specific case where you want to send a form via ajax not make a custom post